# Covariance of a linear and quadratic form of a multivariate normal

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, covariance, quadratic-form

Does anyone know of an explicit matrix expression for the covariance of a linear and quadratic form? That is,

$\mathrm{Cov}[\mathbf{a' y},\mathbf{y' Hy}]$
where $\mathbf{y}\sim \mathcal N(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$.

I'm particularly interested in the case where 
$\boldsymbol{\mu}=\mathbf{0}$, and I think this simplifies (without the normal assumption) to

$\mathbb E[(\mathbf{a'y})(\mathbf{y'Hy})]$. Since this involves cubic terms it probably isn't going to be simple.

Comment: You may find some useful identities in [the matrix cookbook](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). In particular, chapter 6.2 and/or 8.2 may have what you need.

Comment: Ok, with your help of your reference I believe I have proven it is 0 if $\boldsymbol{\mu}=\mathbf{0}$ (still need to check it)

Answer (score 9):

This is straightforward in the case you're interested in (${\boldsymbol \mu} = 0$) without using matrix algebra.

To clarify the notation ${\bf y} = \{y_{1}, ..., y_{n} \}$ is a multivariate normal random vector, ${\bf a} = \{a_{1}, ..., a_{n} \}$ is a row vector, and ${\bf H}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with entries $\{ h_{jk} \}_{j,k=1}^{n}$. By definition (see e.g. [page 3 here](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~st849-1/lectures/Ch02.pdf)) you can re-write this covariance as $$ {\rm cov}({\bf a}'{\bf y}, {\bf y}' {\bf H} {\bf y}) = {\rm cov} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i y_i, \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} h_{jk} y_{j} y_{k} \right) = \sum_{i,j,k} {\rm cov}( a_i y_i, h_{jk} y_{j} y_{k} ) $$ where the second equality follows from [bilinearity of covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Relationship_to_inner_products).  When ${\boldsymbol \mu} = 0$, each term in the sum is $0$ because $${\rm cov}( a_i y_i, h_{jk} y_{j} y_{k} ) \propto E(y_i y_j y_k) - E(y_i) E(y_k y_j) = 0$$ The second term is zero because $E(y_i) = 0$. The first term is zero because [the third order mean-centered moments of a multivariate normal random vector are 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Higher_moments), this can be seen more clearly by looking at the each cases:

- when $i,j,k$ are distinct, then $E(y_i y_j y_k)=0$ by [Isserlis' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem)
- when $i\neq j = k$, then we have $E(y_i y_j y_k) = E(y_i y_{j}^2)$. First we can deduce [from here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) that $E(y_i | y_j=y) = y \cdot \Sigma_{ij}/\Sigma_{jj}$. Therefore, $E(y_{i} y_{j}^2 | y_{j} = y) = y^3 \cdot \Sigma_{ij}/\Sigma_{jj}$. Therefore, by [the law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), $$E(y_i y_{j}^2) = E( E(y_{i} y_{j}^2 | y_{j} = y) ) = E(y^3 \Sigma_{ij}/\Sigma_{jj} ) = E(y^3) \cdot \Sigma_{ij}/\Sigma_{jj} = 0 $$ where $E(y_{j}^3) = 0$  because $y_j$ being symmetrically distributed with mean 0 implies that $y_{j}^3$ is also symmetrically distributed with mean 0.
- when $i=j=k$, $E(y_i y_j y_k) = E(y_{i}^3) = 0$ by the same rationale just given.

Comment: Does Isserlis's theorem also apply in the case when $i, j, k$ are not distinct as would happen in this instance?

Comment: @Dilip, thanks for pointing that out. In that case you don't actually need the theorem, right? For the case where $i=j=k$, $E(y_{i}^3) = 0 $ trivially. For the case where $i=k \neq j$, my intuition is that $y_{j}$ is independent of $y_{i}^2$ since the conditional density of $y_{j} | y_{i}^2 $ (at a particular point $y_{j} = y$) is symmetric in $y_i$, which has mean zero.

Comment: **Hint**: $\mathbf y = \mathbf A \mathbf z$ for some $\mathbf z$ a standard normal vector (possibly of smaller dimension than $\mathbf y$).

Comment: @cardinal, I get that ${\bf A}$ is the cholesky square root of $\Sigma$ and you can use the properties of covariance from there but I was trying to give an answer that didn't require matrix algebra since it only requires [a basic property (a)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Higher_moments) of the multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Hi, Macro. The hint I give does not have anything (really) to do with a Cholesky square root (which may not exist as alluded to in my comment). It uses only the (typical) *definition* of the multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Hi @cardinal, I know you're entertained by commenting in this way but it might just help if you came out and said exactly what you're driving at.

Comment: Hi, Macro. Not "entertained" or trying to be obtuse; just typing on an iPad screen that makes full comments tedious and difficult. I'm sorry the tone of those comments have been interpreted in that way. All I'm suggesting is to use the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definition) of the multivariate normal to reduce the problem to one that is very easy to prove using essentially the same technique as you've given, but with no (unnecessary) reference to Isserlis. This will also expose why the intuition in your first comment is correct.

Comment: In other words: Set $\mathbf b = \mathbf A^T \mathbf a$ and $\widetilde{\mathbf H} = \mathbf A^T \mathbf H \mathbf A$ and use your proof by dealing with $\mathrm{Cov}(  \mathbf b^T \mathbf z, \mathbf z^T \widetilde{\mathbf H}\mathbf z)$. Only the definition of multivariate normality, covariance, independence, and basic properties of the moments of a single iid standard normal random variable are used.

Comment: @cardinal, this is what I figured you were referring to (and what I was sloppily referring to a couple comments ago) but I feel like this adds an additional step that isn't necessary. I do agree that the reference to Isserlis isn't necessary (deleted) and it apparently somewhat distorts my statement  that all third order moments of a mean-zero multivariate normal equal $0$, which I do provide a link for. As it is, I think this answer is correct and self-contained so I'm going to leave it. I may consider editing when I have more time with a proof of the assertion I deferred to a link before.

Comment: Dear Macro, I didn't intend to initiate such a long comment stream and my remarks were only intended to be constructive. Your answer is fine as is; my primary thought was that (as @Dilip alludes to) appealing to the fact that $\mathbb E y_i y_j^2 = 0$ and $\mathbb E y_i y_j y_k = 0$ for zero-mean multivariate normals may appear a bit opaque and this is really where most (or much) of the action actually lies. (It's the only place where any property of normality comes into play.) The comments were intended to show a simple way of bringing out precisely why it was true with no additional work.

Answer (score 5):

This can be proved with multivariate [Stein's Lemma](https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~junliu/TechRept/94folder/siegel.pdf). Letting $x=a'y\sim \mathcal{N}(a'\mu,a'\Sigma a)$, we have that $Cov(x,y) = a'\Sigma$. Let $h(y) = y'Hy$. Stein's lemma then tells us
$$
Cov(x,h(y)) = Cov(x,y)E\left[\nabla h(y)\right] = a'\Sigma E\left[\left(H + H'\right) y\right] = a'\Sigma \left(H + H'\right) \mu.
$$

Some simulations:

```r
library(mvtnorm)

p <- 9
nsim <- 100000
set.seed(1234)
mu <- rnorm(p)
X <- matrix(rnorm(3*p^2),ncol=p)
H <- matrix(rnorm(p^2),ncol=p)
Sigma <- cov(X)
a <- rnorm(p)

Y <- rmvnorm(nsim,mean=mu,sigma=Sigma)
Ya <- Y %*% a
YHY <- rowSums((Y %*% H) * Y)

# empirical
emp <- cov(Ya,YHY)
# theoretical
thr <- a %*% Sigma %*% (H + t(H)) %*% mu
cat('empirical: ',emp,' theoretical: ',thr,' \n')
```

```
empirical:  -2.39  theoretical:  -2.385
```

Answer (score 2):

The covariance between a linear and a quadratic form of a multivariate normal vector is given in [Mathai and Provost](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243770190_Quadratic_Forms_in_Random_Variables), page 74, Theorem 3.2d.2.

Let $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^p \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$, $Q = \mathbf{y}'\mathbf{H}\mathbf{y}$ and $P = \mathbf{a}'\mathbf{y}$, with $\mathbf{H} \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ symmetric and $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^p$.

Then, $Cov(Q,P) = 2 \mathbf{\mu}' \mathbf{H} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{a}$.

In agreement with the other answers, this formula shows that if $\mathbf{\mu} = 0$ the covariance is 0.